# Span inside a Sup HTML element - Why does it behave this way?

Tags: html, css

Putting `span`s inside of a `sup` doesn't apply expecting styling..

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mkms1ozk/2/

You will notice the first `abc` has margin/padding and the `abc` included purely in a sup does not..

I would have thought the margin & padding of 0px would be applied to the span inside the `sup`..

Is this expected behavior?

For the lazy like me here is the entire HTML..

`<html>
<style>
  span{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
  }
</style>
<body>
<sup>
  <span>a</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>c</span>
</sup>
<sup>abc</sup>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: It's whitespace.  If you put all the span tags on one line, the spaces will go away.

Comment: That's because you have whitespace in your HTML. It's the same as [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) (even if `span` are inline by default instead of inline-block)

Comment: @Oriol - technically there's [one technique for removing spaces between inline elements](https://jsfiddle.net/mkms1ozk/3/) that doesn't work with inline-block elements. Not sure how that should be covered.